# I need all columns of a row having maximum ID from each Dept

Tags: mysql, sql

```
ID   Dept   Sal
1    A      10
2    A      20
3    A      34
4    B      22
5    B      54
6    C      65
```

Comment: `select max(id) from tablename 
    group by Dept`

Answer (score 2):

Please try this query...

```
select * from table_name group by dept Having max(id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select * from `table` where id in (select max(id) from `table` group by dept)
```